# Can I get default audio files of Iphone (marimba, alarm, ascending,...)?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ipad

Currently I am working on iPad. I would like to retrieve system audio files by default in iPad (I think it is the same in iPhone). Does anyone know how to retrieve it? I have tried AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID or AVAudioPlayer but I can get these audio files (Marimba, alarm or ascending,...)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can SSH into your device (or root it in any way) you can go to "/System/Library/Audio/UISounds" and they are the audio files are located there. Of course this would mean that you need to jailbreak it.

Comment: You mean I jailbreak iPhone and get those audio files? After that copy to iPad and I develop my app with them.

Do you have any solution using cocoa programming because I don't have any iPhone?

Comment: I'm not an iPhone/iPad developer so I'm not sure what the situation is with their API, but isn't there a way to use those audio files within the API? If not I'm sure somebody has posted them on the internet somewhere. If not that, I can email it you (I only have an iPhone though).

Comment: I have searched internet for this problem and someone have posted the same question like me in this website. The answer like you said above, I need to jailbreak iPhone. If your solution does not harm your device, would you please email me? Thank you very much.

Comment: All the files are in .caf format which can only be opened by Quicktime. I am on a linux box so I can't convert them for you. If you don't have Quicktime you won't be able to play or convert them either, but this link apparently has some (a limited number) of the iPhone sounds. Hopefully the one you want is among them. If not and you have Quicktime, I can email it to you.

EDIT: I forgot to post the link..
http://mark.koli.ch/2008/11/03/i_phone_sys_sound_mp3.zip

Comment: Thank for your link. These file are Mp3 format, not in caf format. I have Quicktime and I can open them. Thank for your help. :-)

Comment: No problem. I meant that the files I had are in .caf and there are some sounds that I have that are not in the link. But if the ones you need are there, problem solved! Good luck!