# Using iPhone default Alarm sounds in application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ringtone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Play alert sound (same as default message ringtone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250200/play-alert-sound-same-as-default-message-ringtone)

Hello all,

Quick question -
Is it possible to use one of the default sounds included on the iPhone - Marimba etc. in an iPhone application?

Thanks, 
Teja

Comment: If I were you I would just include the files as resources within your app.  Why risk rejection by using undocumented stuff? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual directories will only be accessible after JailBreak.

**Ringtones (including Marimba):**

```
/Library/Ringtones/
```

**System sounds:**

```
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/
```

Or use 'AudioServicesPlaySystemSound()' like mentioned by Black Frog.
Note: This method is undocumented and will cause AppStore rejection.

Download link for system sounds (comment by clusterfu_k):
[Can I get default audio files of Iphone (marimba, alarm, ascending,...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090890/can-i-get-default-audio-files-of-iphone-marimba-alarm-ascending)
Note: Possible copyright infringement.

Comment: Thanks, Do you think I'll have any problems with the AppStore approval process by downloading+including these though? Maybe I should just make some. Default tunes on Pianos are probably good enough.

Comment: I doubt Apple will accept applications that contain their own copyrighted material. Officially they reject it, but I think it might just slip through.

Comment: The above mentioned directories are available on my iPhone 4S, iOS 7.0 without jailbreak.