# Default Ringtone on a VOIP app in iOS

Tags: ios, voip, ringtone

I'm trying to find a way to use the default ringtone of an incoming call on an iPhone device.

Currently, I'm using the AVAudioplayer, i.e.

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"CustomSound"];
AVAudioPlayer *aplayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
aplayer.numberOfLoops=-1;
[aplayer play]
```

Is it possible to find the default Ringtone sound of the user and play it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way is to use CallKit.  Your VoIP app will then get a lot of stuff for "free".  When you inject an incoming call using CallKit, iOS will automatically play the proper ringtone.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit

Answer (score 0):

there is no Public API for that, this was asked on SO in 2012 but it is still true today I think

see: [How do I play the default Phone ringtone programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577811/how-do-i-play-the-default-phone-ringtone-programmatically)

---

with undocumented enum values AudioServicesPlaySystemSound can do it but thats NOT really appstore safe.

see: [Play alert sound (same as default message ringtone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250200/play-alert-sound-same-as-default-message-ringtone)

---

#### advice:

maybe use `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` as: Sounds play at the current system audio volume, with no programmatic volume control available