# Play user's selected ringtone or notification sound using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer

Is it possible play the user's selected ringtone or notification sound using AVAudioPlayer?

I've read we can play systems sounds using AudioServicesPlaySystemSound, like AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1003), but I really need to play the sounds the user has selected as the ringtone or as notification or alarm sounds.

In Android this is possible using the following:

```
RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM
RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION
RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE
```

Is this possible in iOS 10 and above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I play the default Phone ringtone programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577811/how-do-i-play-the-default-phone-ringtone-programmatically)